# Does purge action result in some packages no longer required?

Tags: apt, package-management

I want to upgrade the qbittorrent by compile the latest version.

```
sudo apt purge qbittorrent
```

Some info pop up:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python3-selinux python3-slip python3-slip-dbus
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

Are the packages `python3-selinux python3-slip python3-slip-dbus` related with `qbittorrent`?
Does `apt purge qbittorrent` result in `some packages no longer required` ?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://askubuntu.com/q/402589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `apt`, it tells you about any automatically removable packages after calculating the result of whatever you’re asking it to do. This includes both packages which were already automatically removable before the `apt` invocation, as a result of previous package removals, and packages which will be automatically removable as a result of the requested operations.

In this particular instance, the listed packages aren’t related to `qbittorrent`, and its removal won’t have made them automatically removable; they already were.